# error: <identifier> expected

Tags: java

When I try to compile the Report.java I'm getting an error on line 6 saying: `error: <identifier> expected aClient.setClientName("Michael");` with and arrow pointing to the first parenthese.

```
public class Client {

    private String _clientName;

    public String getClientName(){
        return _clientName;
    }
    public void setClientName(String clientName){
        _clientName = clientName;
    }

}
public class Report {

    Client aClient = new Client();
    //ClientLawn aClientLawn = new ClientLawn();

    aClient.setClientName("Michael");
    //aClientLawn.setLawnWidth(10);
    //aClientLawn.setLawnLength(10);

    public void output(){
        System.out.println(aClient.getClientName());
        //System.out.println(aClientLawn.calcLawnSize());
    }

}
```

I also want to make note that I am new to Java so please be gentle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line should be put into an initializer block:

```
{
    aClient.setClientName("Michael");
}
```

So it it executed after creating the `aClient`.

The code here is run for every instance of the `Report`. Unfortunately you cannot set parameters to it. If you want to do so, put this block into the constructor:

```
public Report (String clientName) {
    aClient.setClientName(clientName);
    //aClientLawn.setLawnWidth(10);
    //aClientLawn.setLawnLength(10);
}
```

Comment: In this context, they are called `Initializer blocks`. An anonymous block is used to restrict scope of variables within a method.

Answer (score 3):

Use `instance initialization block`.

```
public class Report {

    Client aClient = new Client();
    //ClientLawn aClientLawn = new ClientLawn();
    {
        aClient.setClientName("Michael");
        //aClientLawn.setLawnWidth(10);
        //aClientLawn.setLawnLength(10);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As everybody else pointed out, you cannot execute code outside of a method, so the following lines are illegal:

```
Client aClient = new Client();
aClient.setClientName("Michael");
```

They need to be wrapped within a method, such as the class' constructor:

```
public class Report {
    public Report() {
        Client aClient = new Client();
        aClient.setClientName("Michael");
    }

    // ....
}
```

It looks like you want this code to be executable though, in which case you want to put all that in a `main` method such as:

```
public class Report {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Client aClient = new Client();
        aClient.setClientName("Michael");
        System.out.println(aClient.getName());
    }
}
```

You can then compile and execute the `Report` class.